# A word that describes something being emotional, intellectual, physical, spiritual..etc

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I was thinking *multifaceted*, but I am interested in other suggestions

Context:

Discoveries are / can be / emotional, spiritual..etc

As formal as possible please, but I'm open to suggestions (i.e. I do not want obscure 1700s idiomatic phrases)

Comment: Please [edit] this to explain how you want to use the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holistic
: relating to or concerned with complete systems rather than with individual parts

Comprehensive 
: including many, most, or all things

Wide-ranging
: including many different ideas, actions, or things
(definitions from Merriam-Webster)

Intricate, Complex, Sophisticated may also work

Comment: I like and agree with these particular word choices.